# Combining CSV files in R

Tags: r

I am having trouble combining multiple CSV files while preserving new columns and combining rows with same cell name.

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

d1 <- read.csv("week1.csv")
d2 <- read.csv("week2.csv")

df <- merge(d1,d2)
```

This is not doing what I want it to do exactly.

Both CSV files have address rows that can overlap with each other as well as a row with an integer corresponding to the address. the overlapping addresses in both CSV files should conserve the address and only add both integers together.

Comment: May be you need `bind_rows(d1, d2)`

Comment: Or perhaps `left_join()`.

Comment: You need to specify the `by=...` argument, to tell the `merge` function which columns to use to merge the datasets. Specifying the `all=...` argument would help too.

Comment: I tried using by and all and it's creating a new column with integers and NA values